# 10 Million records = wiped MySQL DB?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, database-administration

So I was trying to load some test data and it appears to have killed my *entire* database. This is one case where it's great to have backups! They were all plain insert queries, probably about a 900 MB file. What could have gone wrong?

When I woke up (I let it run overnight) `mysql` was not responding at all, prompting a reboot of the server to fix it. Then I got `code 28` errors when attempting to list any tables.

Is there something I can use to guard against this in the future?

Comment: code 28 = out of disk space. free some disk space!

Comment: Disk space. Ug. The one thing I did not check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that the data you are loading may be 900mb outside of your RDBMS but may be even more in the database with out compression. You also have to accout for database growth if it does it in chunks and transaction log space. So always be sure you have ample disk space when doing that large of an import of data as it seems that code is a direct result of [running out of disk space](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html).

Answer (score 1):

If i remember well error 28 should be for some problems writing on files.
Were some file systems full at the time of the error? Maybe /tmp (or c:\temp) were full?

Comment: Linux baby, linux. ;)